# Get entity with ordered items by field from OneToOne relation in item

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have the next model:

Manifest entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "shipping_manifest")
public class Manifest {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    // other fields

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, mappedBy = "manifest")
//    @OrderBy("appOrder.orderNO")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Set<ShippingLabel> labels;
}
```

Label entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "shipping_label")
public class ShippingLabel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    // other fields

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "manifest_id", nullable = false)
    private Manifest manifest;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH} , fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private Order appOrder;
}
```

Order entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_order")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "order_no", nullable = false)
    private Long orderNO;

    // other fields

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "appOrder")
    private ShippingLabel label;
}
```

Is it possible to get Manifest entity with ordered ShippingLabels by orderNO feild from Order entity?

I read in javadoc about `@OrderBy` annotation but it allows dot notation only for Embadded fields.

P.S. I am using Spring Data and Hibernate as JPA implementation.

Comment: @Plog, you want to say that it is not possible?

Comment: Well its not possible using @OrderBy. The answer to the question I linked provides some alernative approaches using queries and comparators for sorting in memory though.

Comment: @Plog, thanks a lot